# Jest .toHaveBeenCalled() not recording function calls

Tags: jestjs, mocking, nestjs

I'm testing a service in my NestJs application which calls a factory to receive an object with a method *up()*, which I'm mocking like this:

```
export const mockExecutorFactory = {
   getExecutor: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
       return {
           up: jest.fn().mockImplementation((_updatedInstance, _parameters) => {
               console.log('****************************');
               return Promise.resolve({ successful: true });
           }),
       };
   }),
};
```

In my *describe* block for the service test I initialize the executor like this:

```
let executor;

beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        providers: [
            InstanceService,
            { provide: getRepositoryToken(Instance), useValue: mockInstanceRepository },
            ExecutorFactory,
        ],
    })
        .overrideProvider(ExecutorFactory)
        .useValue(mockExecutorFactory)
        .compile();

    service = module.get<InstanceService>(InstanceService);
    executor = module.get<ExecutorFactory>(ExecutorFactory).getExecutor();
});
```

And the test its self is written like this:

```
    it('should create a new instance with default settings', async () => {
    // Check if instance created correctly
    expect(
        await service.createInstance(
            MOCK_INSTANCE_CREATE_PARAMS.solutionId,
            MOCK_INSTANCE_CREATE_PARAMS.instanceType,
            MOCK_INSTANCE_CREATE_PARAMS.orgId,
            MOCK_INSTANCE_CREATE_PARAMS.parameters,
            MOCK_INSTANCE_CREATE_PARAMS.customPrice,
            true,
            MOCK_INSTANCE_CREATE_PARAMS.req,
        ),
    ).toEqual({ instance: MOCK_INSTANCE_DEFAULT });

    console.log(executor);
    expect(executor.up).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Essentially, the *createInstance()* runs through some logic and at the end is supposed to call the executor's *up()* function.

From the terminal output (photo below) I can see by the console logs that the the *up()* is being called, but the test fails... Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: Can you try making `executor` not a mock function, jsut a regular arrow function?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, same error

Comment: Hmm, normally I would think this would be because the `up` you got from `executor.up` is not the same `up` as the one that was called.

Comment: But the console logs verify that it is that one right.... I'll play around with it a bit more

Comment: Which would mean that each time you call `executor.up` you're getting a new version of `executor.up`.